# How to capture entire webpage in iPhone safari?

Tags: iphone, screen-scraping, mobile-safari, screenshot

Like in Firefox (Desktop version) I can take using [Fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/)

and in Android mobile I can take using [Dolphin Screen Cut](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.ScreenCut)

I already know that we take screendump using wake+home it doesn't take screencapture of whole webpage including the area under the scroll and  it would be difficult to take multiple screenshots by pressing wake+home and scrolling in between but with this there will be small overlap between shots and thee combine screenshot will not be precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After-all I found the solution

This app worked for me perfectly

[Website Screenshot](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/website-screenshot/id437683442?mt=8#) (iPhone app)

Answer (score 3):

[Barry — Webpage screenshot](http://barryapp.com/) does the trick. You can capture full length webpage screenshots and save them to Camera Roll or Copy to clipboard for pasting into any app that supports pasting in images.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to do this in Mobile Safari.

If you're developing an application (and since this is stackoverflow I'll assume that's what you're talking about) and using a `UIWebView` you could do this - you would need to:

1. Calculate the total height of the webpage you want to capture
2. Use a `UIWebView` with the height obtained above to display your webpage at actual size
3. Render that `UIWebView` as an image in an off-screen buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Webpage Capture for iPhone | iPad : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webpage-capture/id348797820?mt=8